# Exact Equivalent of IOS auto resizing and spacing tableview for android

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, uitableview, android-recyclerview

Is there any Equivalent of IOS auto resizing and spacing tableview for android.
Like example see in below Image. Button moved to bottom of the screen leaving spaces between above cells and button cell automatically. I heard this spacing happening automatically in IOS, need to implement exact replica in android inside recyclerview or some listview. How to achieve this perfectly?

[image]